# Ambiguous guarded pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

The future 4.03 release of OCaml has added a new warning, `57`, to prevent [ambiguous guarded pattern](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=7031). Namely, the issue is that on an or-pattern with a `when` clause, if the first part of the or-pat matches, but the `when` evaluates to `false`, the complete pattern will be discarded, although another variant of the or-pat could have succeed. For instance, on the following code, `ko` will be bound to `1`, which can be surprising:

```
type t = A of string | B of string

let bad x y =
  match x,y with
  | A s, _ | _, A s when s = "foo" -> 0
  | _, _ -> 1

let ok = bad (A "foo") (A "bar")
let ko = bad (A "bar") (A "foo")
```

In 4.03, OCaml will complain with `Warning 57: Ambiguous guarded pattern, variable s may match different or-pattern arguments`, suggesting you to check whether you really intended this behavior or not.

However, the warning is also active on the second line of the pattern matching in the following definition:

```
let f x y =
  match  x,y with
  | A _, A _ -> 0
  | A s, _  | _, A s when s = "foo" -> 1
  | _ -> 2
```

Here, I'd argue that the ambiguity cannot arise, since `A _, A _` is matched by the first line, hence at most one of the components of the or-pattern can match if the program gets to this point. Is this reasoning correct?

If the answer is yes, I would like to know in addition whether it is possible to silence this warning on this specific branch. Indeed, I can do `match [@warning "-57"] x,y with`, but this will silence the warning if someone introduces another ambiguous pattern there sometime later. I've tried to put the attribute at the pattern level (`| A s, _ | _, A s [@warning "-57"] when s = "foo"`), but this has no effect.

NB: I know that in this specific case I could just replace the catch-all with `| A s, B _ | B _, A s when s = "foo"` to make the ambiguity disappear, but consider that this is only a reduced example.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is for people unaware that `when` guards are not part of the pattern and imagine that `A s, _ | _, A s when s = ""` is the same as `A s, _ | (_, A s when s = "")` which is syntactically invalid.

It seems like a good idea to keep the warning, although it would be nice if explicit parentheses prevented it, e.g. `(A s, _ | _, A s) when s = ""`.

You're suggesting that the compiler should be smarter than the average reader and suppress warnings based on non-obvious rules. In other words your reasoning is correct but it's too much overhead for the programmer who is used to rely on warnings.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that the compiler should be smarter, I'd just like to have a way to tell it: "trust me for _this particular pattern_ I know what I'm doing", without having to discard the warning for the entire pattern-matching expression.

Comment: I guess a directive to turn on or off warnings locally would be useful.